# Jquery finding all child links

Tags: jquery

In jquery I can find the content of all li's like so

```
$("#myid").closest('li').html())
```

How can I find all the href inside myid li?

This is my html

```
<div id="myid">

            <li> <a href="show1">showroom1</a> </li>
            <li> <a href="show2">showroom2</a> </li>
            <li> <a href="show3">showroom3</a> </li>

            </div>
```

This code  `$("#myid").closest('li').html())` gives me showroom1, showroom2 and showroom3. What if I want to get the hrefs, how would I do that. Like show1, show2 and show3.

I attempted

```
($("#myid").closest('li').closest('a').attr('href'))
```

But it never worked. I get undefined.

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can iterate over the list items using `.each()` and then find the href value by using `.attr('href')`.

```
$('#myid li').each(function(){
    console.log( $(this).find('a').attr('href') );
});
```

**[jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/A86b2/)**

Answer (score 1):

Use the `find` method and then loop through the items returned by the find

```
$(function(){  
   var allAs=$("#myid li").find("a");
   $.each(allAs,function(index,item){
      alert($(item).attr("href"));
   }); 
});
```

jsfiddle sample : http://jsfiddle.net/xPa8m/3/

Comment: Thanks for the prompt reply, I attempted your way but never worked. So I used j08691  Cheers

Comment: I Guess your markup is then different than what you posted. The code works fine. Check the jsfiddle i posted in my answer.

Comment: Yes you are right it does work, the problem was I was using it inside my ready function and your code defines one already. Thanks